# React native android expo TaskQueue: Error with task: undefined is not a function

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo

I tried to implement `onViewableItemsChanged`, it work on iOS but it crashed when run on Android, both devices and emulators.

**Environment:**

```
OS: macOS 10.14
Node: 8.12.0
Yarn: 1.10.1
npm: 6.4.1
Watchman: Not Found
Xcode: Xcode 10.1 Build version 10B61
Android Studio: 3.2 AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338
```

Packages: (wanted => installed)

```
react: 16.3.1 => 16.3.1
react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-29.0.0.tar.gz => 0.55.4
```

**Error message:**

> TaskQueue: Error with task: undefined is not a function (evaluating
>   '_iteratortypeof Symbol === "function" ? Symbol.iterator :
>   "@@iterator"')

[image]
[image: error message]

**Code:**

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.handleMethod = this.handleMethod.bind(this)
}


handleMethod = ({ viewableItems, changed}) =>{
   console.log("hey");
}
render() {
  return (
   <FlatList
      data={this.state.newsfeed}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
      refreshControl={this._refreshControl()}
      renderItem={({ item, index }) => this.renderNewsItem(item, index)}
      ref={component => {
        this.scroll = component;
      }}
      onViewableItemsChanged={this.handleMethod}
      onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
      onScroll={this.handleScroll}
  />
  )}
```

Comment: I hope you have updated version react native ? I was facing that issue due to older version.

Comment: @QuokMoon the current react-native version of expo is 0.55.4. Is this version suppose to have a bug? If so, I might have to look for another method to get current index of flatlist. Any suggestion?